# Its about asp.net application that uses MVC 2.0 artcitecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Currently i am working on asp.net MVC-2 applications. i met with a problem that how to get signup form data into controller class. There is a solution that we can use FormCollection object but how to get individual field values.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

The *simplest* way to handle posted values is with the `FormCollection` object you mentioned. You can access it like an array:

```
public ActionResult YourAction(FormCollection form)
{
    // assuming a form element posted with the name, "user"
    var user = FormCollection["user"];
    return View();
}
```

The *best* way to handle posted values is by using a strongly typed view model. The view model would contain properties of your form. The MVC framework will automagically bind your form elements to this object, if possible.

So, your view model class might look like:

```
public class UserFormViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

If your HTML form contained two inputs with their *name* attributes set to `Username` and `Age`, then your controller action could be modified to use the strongly types view model just described:

```
public ActionResult UserForm(UserFormViewModel vm)
{
    string username = vm.Username;
    int age = vm.Age;

    // persist to database, etc
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go and download the following project.  There is a free pdf document.  Work through the entire sample.  It makes you understand all the basics you need to know about asp.net mvc framework

[Mvc Music Store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/)

And also if you create a default mvc project in visual studio, it should show you how to handle the signup form in the Register action.